# Swift : Use closure compatible with Objective-C block

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I tried to define a closure using the following Objective-C blocks:

```
typedef void(^UPBaseEventAPIArrayCompletion)(NSArray *results, UPURLResponse *response, NSError *error);

+ (void)getFriendsWithCompletion:(UPBaseEventAPIArrayCompletion)completion;
```

in this:

```
UPUserAPI.getFriendsWithCompletion({(friends: [AnyObject], response: UPURLResponse, error: NSErrorPointer) -> Void in

    })
```

... and got the following error (see image):

Cannot convert value of type '([AnyObject], UPURLResponse, NSErrorPointer) -> Void' to expected argument type 'UPBaseEventAPIArrayCompletion!'

[image]

What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: Good question. Do not add *Please*, *Thanks*, or other email communication protocol in posts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
UPUserAPI.getFriendsWithCompletion({(friends: [AnyObject]?, response: UPURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    //code 
})
```

In the Objective C code, any of those parameters could be nil. So in Swift, these parameters have to be defined as Optionals.

Comment: I edited my response to change NSErrorPointer to NSError? Does this work?

Comment: Yeah! The error is gone. Thank you so much. Why exactly this happened?

Comment: Check out this article about optional types in Swift.

http://appventure.me/2014/06/13/swift-optionals-made-simple/