# Using closure Swift which is declared as block in Objective C in Swift 2.1

Tags: objective-c, swift, closures, objective-c-blocks

I have a block declare in Objective C file like this :

```
- (void) getUserCurrentProfile:(void (^)(UserInfo *userInfo,NSError * error)) callBack {
if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
    //code here
   }];
}
```

in Swift file I call it :

```
func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!) {
FBManager.getUserCurrentProfile({(userInfo:UserInfo?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
  appDelegate.showHomeView()
})
```

But I totally get this error again :

[image]

Can anyone give me an idea?

P/S: I read this issue : [Swift : Use closure compatible with Objective-C block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33903088/swift-use-closure-compatible-with-objective-c-block). And do the same thing. But it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getUserCurrentProfile` is an instance method, and you are calling it as a class method. You should call it on an instance of `FBManager` (`sharedInstance` maybe?):

```
FBManager.sharedInstance.getUserCurrentProfile { userInfo, error in)
    appDelegate.showHomeView()
}
```

The error says that it cannot convert the closure to `FBManager`, and is correct, as you are calling it as a class function and the compiler expects and instance to operate on. The above call could have also been written in the curried function call:

```
FBManager.getUserCurrentProfile(FBManager.sharedInstance) { userInfo, error in)
    appDelegate.showHomeView()
}
```